# Angular 1.5: Access bindToController properties inside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm learning how to properly use the bindToController feature of custom directives and wondering how to access the properties you declare in the bindToController object from the directive controller.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[])
  .directive('myDir', MyDir)
  .controller('MyCtrl',['$scope', MyCtrlFn]);

function MyCtrlFn($scope) {
  var ctrl = this;
  this.ctrlStr = '';
  this.ctrlAsStr = '';
  $scope.$watch(this.name, function(newValue) {
    if(newValue) ctrl.ctrlStr += ' '+newValue;
  })
  $scope.$watch('ctrl.name', function(newValue) {
    if(newValue) ctrl.ctrlAsStr += ' '+newValue;
  })
}

function MyDir() {
  return {
    template: '<div>{{ctrl.name}}</div>'+
    '<div>CtrlStr: {{ctrl.ctrlStr}}</div>'+
    '<div>CtrlAsStr: {{ctrl.ctrlAsStr}}</div>',
    scope: {},
      bindToController: {
          name: '='
      },
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: 'MyCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'ctrl'
  }
}
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jrtc1bLo/2/

So I thought the properties were bound to the controller but it seems they're rather bound to the controller alias in the scope.

What's the good way to access them from the controller ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what it is you're trying to do here? I think you may be misusing bindToController unknowingly. It is possible you could avoid it all together and just use a parent scope.

Comment: `$scope.$watch('ctrl.name', ...` won't bind to anything useful as you are binding `name` to the controller not to the scope. You should do `$scope.$watch(function() { return this.name; }, ...)`?

Comment: @Mike The second part of your answer is almost right but `this` does not refer to my controller, so `return ctrl.name` works (cf @georgeawg answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you correct your first watcher, you will see that your controller is bound correctly.

```
function MyCtrlFn($scope) {
  var ctrl = this;
  this.ctrlStr = '';
  this.ctrlAsStr = '';
  //DO THIS
  $scope.$watch(function(){return ctrl.name}, function(newValue) {    
  // NOT THIS
  //$scope.$watch(this.name, function(newValue) {
    if(newValue) ctrl.ctrlStr += ' '+newValue;
  })
  $scope.$watch('ctrl.name', function(newValue) {
    if(newValue) ctrl.ctrlAsStr += ' '+newValue;
  })
}
```

The first argument to `$watch` is either a function that is evaluated every digest cycle or an Angular expression in string form which is evaluated each digest cycle.

With the correction, both watchers will see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example:

```
angular
    .module('form')
    .controller('FormGroupItemController', FormGroupItemController)
    .directive('formGroupItem', formGroupItem);

function FormGroupItemController(){}

function formGroupItem() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            errors: '=',
            submit: '='
        },
        bindToController: true,
        controller: 'FormGroupItemController as vm',
        templateUrl: 'app/form/form-group-item.html'
    };

    return directive;
}
```

As you can see, I have a `form-group-item` directive. I use it in my HTML like so:

```
<div form-group-item model="vm.username" errors="vm.errors" submit="vm.updateUsername"></div>
```

Here I take three things from the scope that the directive was used in, and I essentially duplicate them (bind them to the controller) of the directive itself. Those three things are: **model**, **errors**, and **submit**.

The errors are a bag of possible errors (array), the model is just a value to watch, and the submit is a submit function.

Now those three things are within the scope of `FormGroupItemController`, and I can use them in the `form-group-item.html` as a `$scope` or `controllerAs`, whichever I specified. In this case, I use controllerAs syntax.

So before the directive has anything binded to it's controller, it's just an empty constructor like this:

```
function FormGroupItemController() {}
```

After the bind, it will look like this:

```
function FormGroupItemController() {
    this.model = 'blah';
    this.errors = [...];
    this.submit = function(...) {...}
}
```

Comment: What if you want to make some computation on `model`, `errors` or `submit` from your FormGroupItemController ? Like checking the model is ok, or formatting the errors ?

Comment: You can do anything you'd like within the FormGrouItemController. This is just a basic sort of base to show how you bind functionality of one controller to the controller of a directive. Once you have them binded, you can do whatever you'd like.

Comment: Edited to show you what the controller would look like when you bind..then you can access/manipulate them just like any other controller.